# PHP Grabbing the File Input

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a form that looks like:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="control-group">
            <input type="file" class="input-xlarge" name="aisis_file" placeholder="Your file.">
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX" value="1024"></div><div></div><div class="control-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload Zip" name="aisis_upload">
        </div>
    </fieldset> 
</form>
```

This then interacts with some PHP I wrote:

```
if($_POST['aisis_upload']){
    $upload = new AisisCore_FileHandling_Upload_Upload($_FILE['aisis_file']);
}
```

All I am doing (when passing in the name) is var dumping the file object out in the classes constructor to see some objects to then go from there. the problem is it comes back null even if I upload a simple .txt file.

I thought you use the name of the file input element....

Comment: The [Handling file uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/features.file-upload.php) documentation contains complete details and helpful examples about interacting with uploaded files.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing **enctype="multipart/form-data"** in the form . Also you have used `$_FILE` which is **wrong** it should be `$_FILES`

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="control-group">
            <input type="file" class="input-xlarge" name="aisis_file" placeholder="Your file.">
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX" value="1024"></div><div></div><div class="control-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload Zip" name="aisis_upload">
        </div>
    </fieldset> 
</form>
<?php

    if($_POST['aisis_upload']){
        $upload = new AisisCore_FileHandling_Upload_Upload($_FILES['aisis_file']);
    }
?>
```

Comment: still giving me null. the constructor takes in a param of type array $file. which, my understanding is that the object `$_FILE['aisis_file']` will return an array of information about the file.

Comment: is it $_FILE OR $_FILES :)

Comment: Fixed that, it is `$_FILES` >.> Now instead of xdebug spazzing out, the vardump works....`null`. I tried uploading, as a test, a .ini file from some app. i should have gotten an array of info about that file no?

Comment: I have and it now spazzes out saying undefined index 'aisis_file' if I do a `print_r($_POST['aisis_file'])` I see my file I uploaded, well the name of it any ways, but `print_r($_FILES['aisis_file'])` doesn't work.

Comment: Also: `Array ( [aisis_file] => 02808_ladamedefer_1920x1080.jpg [MAX] => 1024 [aisis_upload] => Upload Zip )` is a `print_r($_POST)`